# autocomplete pegar multiples elementos

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

tengo un componente de [primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) `p:autocomplete` mi pregunta es si es posible pegar varios elementos a la vez.

El componente:

```
<p:autoComplete dropdown="true" id="instalacion" maxResults="100" 
    value="#{principalView.cochesSeleccionados}" 
    completeMethod="#{principalView.completeText}"
    forceSelection="true" multiple="true" 
    emptyMessage="Ningun dato coincide">

</p:autoComplete>
```

El bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="principalView")
@ViewScoped
public class PrincipalView {
    List<String> results;
    List<String> cochesSeleccionados;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        results = new ArrayList<String>();
        results.add("BMW");
        results.add("AUDI");
        results.add("SEAT");
    }

    public List<String> completeText(String query) {
        return results;
    }
    // gettter and setter
    public List<String> getCochesSeleccionados() {
        return cochesSeleccionados;
    }

    public void setCochesSeleccionados(List<String> cochesSeleccionados) {
        this.cochesSeleccionados = cochesSeleccionados;
    }
}
```

Mi intencion es poder copiar de un sitio los elementos:

> BMW   SEAT
>   y al pegarlo en el componente que se seleccione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo conseguí poniendo un botón que abre un modal con un `inputTextArea` donde pegaremos la lista de elementos a pegar.

```
<p:autoComplete dropdown="true" id="autocomplete_coches" maxResults="100" 
    value="#{principalView.cochesSeleccionados}" 
    completeMethod="#{principalView.completeText}"
    forceSelection="true" multiple="true" 
    emptyMessage="Ningun dato coincide">
</p:autoComplete>

<p:commandButton value=" " icon="fa fa-plus" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg4').show();" style="height: 31.19;width:30px;"/>
<p:dialog header="Coches" widgetVar="dlg4" minHeight="40">
    <p:inputTextarea  rows="10" cols="50" autoResize="false" value="#{principalView.textArea}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Añadir" actionListener="#{principalView.multipleElemento()}" update="autocomplete_coches" oncomplete="PF('dlg4').hide();"></p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('dlg4').hide();"></p:commandButton>
</p:dialog>
```

La parte Java:

```
    private String textArea;

    public void multipleElemento() {
        String[] lista =textArea.split("\n");//El usuario pega los diferentes elementos con un salto de linea.

        for(String coche : lista) {

            if(cochesSeleccionados == null) {
                cochesSeleccionados = new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            if(coche != null && coche.size()==1)
                cochesSeleccionados.add(coche);
        }
        textArea="";
    }
```

Obviamente ahora si pegamos cualquier elemento en el inputTextarea lo va a poner como si existiera.

Answer (score 0):

Hola no he visto mucho del tema. pero espero que te pueda ayudar.. 
revise la pagina de PrimeFaces

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

hay un ejemplo practico de multiselect que me parece que estas buscando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero sea de tu ayuda

Comment: Hola, lo que busco es poder pegar 2 o más elementos y que se seleccionen a la vez, gracias.